# when click legend item in chart.js my bar is hiden but value of bar not hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chart.js

this is my html code:

```
<div class="chart col-md-12">
 <canvas id="bar-chart-grouped2" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 400px; max-width: 100%;margin-top:1%;"></canvas>
</div>
```

and chartjs code

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-grouped"), {
               type: 'bar',
               data: {
                   labels:  <%=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Date_Solar_Index)%>,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Total_Recived",
                        backgroundColor: "#17a2b8",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        borderColor: '#e2e2e2',
                        borderWidth: '2',
                        data:<%=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(POID_MMS_Index)%>,
                    }, {
                        label: "valideted",
                        backgroundColor: "#28a745",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        borderColor: '#e2e2e2',
                        borderWidth: '2',
                        data:  <%=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(COW_POID_MMS_Index)%>,
                    }, {
                        label: "Total_rejected",
                        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        borderColor: '#e2e2e2',
                        borderWidth: '2',
                        data: <%=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MNP_POID_MMS_Index)%>,
                    }, {
                        label: "Total_Back log",
                        backgroundColor: "#ffc107",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        borderColor: '#e2e2e2',
                        borderWidth: '2',
                        data:  <%=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Supervisions_Index)%>,
                    }, {
                        label: "Total_Back log",
                        backgroundColor: "#B60A3B",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        borderColor: '#e2e2e2',
                        borderWidth: '2',
                        data:  <%=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(INDEXED_Index)%>,
                    }, {
                        label: "Total_Back log",
                        backgroundColor: "#72098E",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                        borderColor: '#e2e2e2',
                        borderWidth: '2',
                        data:  <%=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Reject_Index)%>,
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: ''
                },
                legend: { display: true, position: "bottom", onClick: null },
                hover: {
                    animationDuration: 0
                },


                animation: {
                    onComplete: function () {
                        var chartInstance = this.chart;
                        var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                        ctx.response = true;
                        ctx.textAlign = "center";
                        ctx.font = "bold  Arial";
                        //ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                        Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                            Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                ctx.save();
                                // Translate 0,0 to the point you want the text
                                ctx.translate(bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 20);

                                // Rotate context by -90 degrees
                                ctx.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);

                                // Draw text
                                ctx.fillText(dataset.data[index], 0, 0);
                                ctx.restore();
                            }), this)
                        }), this);
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",

                        },
                        id: 'B',
                        type: 'linear',
                        display: false,
                        position: 'left',

                    }, {
                        gridLines: {
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                        },
                        id: 'A',
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'right',
                        display: false,
                        ticks: {

                            max: 101,
                            min: 0
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W0Vj.jpg)

Comment: make clear your question, add a screenshot of your resault

Comment: dear ali thanks for your help screen shot from here enter https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W0Vj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you have overriden the default onClick method for the legend `legend: { display: true, position: "bottom", onClick: null }` remove the `onClick: null` and try again. It should work then

EDIT: Dear, in your afterDraw you never check if the dataset is hidden you always draw te text. And since the data is still in the data object it will just draw it

Comment: dear I disable this property because not right showing when onClick is true  T you can show result in this picture i attached .  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W0Vj.jpg